# Google Plus like column layout in angular and flex-layout

Tags: angular, css, flexbox, angular-flex-layout

I am trying to realize a "Google Plus like" multi-column responsive page layout with angular and flex-layout.

i have the responsive multi columns working.
- see the [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-enterprisebug)

but how to arrange the row layout that it stacks?
I am trying:

```
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayout.xs="column" fxLayoutWrap>
    <card1 fxFlex fxFlex.gt-sm="33" fxFlex.sm="50"></card1>
    <card1 fxFlex fxFlex.gt-sm="33" fxFlex.sm="50"></card1>
    <card1 fxFlex fxFlex.gt-sm="33" fxFlex.sm="50"></card1>
    <card1 fxFlex fxFlex.gt-sm="33" fxFlex.sm="50"></card1>
    <card1 fxFlex fxFlex.gt-sm="33" fxFlex.sm="50"></card1>
    <card1 fxFlex fxFlex.gt-sm="33" fxFlex.sm="50"></card1>
    <card1 fxFlex fxFlex.gt-sm="33" fxFlex.sm="50"></card1>
</div>
```

but this doesn't "stack" the cards.

this is what i like to achieve:
[image]

Comment: You will need Angular and Masonry to accomplish that ... https://github.com/passy/angular-masonry

Comment: @LGSon thanks for the hint. I will give it a try. At least i know what to search for now. Thanks!

Comment: Hello, I'm looking for that answer now, I need exactly this to achive. May I ask did you figure it out?

Comment: @SenTisso angular-masonry did the Job